# How to perform autorestart of Pods at scheduled time in openshift

Tags: docker, containers, openshift, openshift-client-tools, automated-deploy

I am having a list of pods running java applications,want to have a schedule restart of pods automatically.How it can be performed.I have tried with having a cron job inside an ocp file but it didn't work.

Help me with some suggestions

Comment: Without any more details than " it didn't work." no one will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

If the CronJob didn't work, you likely need to authorize the ServiceAccount running the CronJob Pod to be able to list & delete the Java Pods. Otherwise it will lack the permissions to do so.

There are a long list of alternatives, but the constraints of your environment and the motivation to restart the applications would be important to understand to determine a good approach. Examples:

- Add a Rest API to the Java application which can trigger graceful shutdown and trigger it from the CronJob.
- If you don't really need this to be scheduled and it will suffice to be periodic restart, consider setting `pod.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` . This will ensure the Pod terminates after running for the specified duration.
- [Share the process namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/) between containers in the Java Pod and add a container that kills Java process at the scheduled time.